# STL priority queue and overloading with pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue

This is my first time using a priority queue. I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm for school and I figured I need a min heap to do this. Right now my nodes are pointers and I want to compare their weight, but I don't think I can overload > and < with pointers? Is there a way I could accomplish this?

Code this far:

```
priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, node_comparison> minHeap;
```

And then I have a struct to compare the node's weights

```
struct node_comparison 
{
   bool operator<( const Node* a, const Node* b ) const 
   {
    return a->totalWeight < b->totalWeight;
   }
};
```

However it says there are too many parameters for this operator function. I've been trying to figure out how I could manage a min heap priority queue with my nodes for a while now and keep getting stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: In [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), see [the example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue#Example) which uses [`std::less<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). You need to implement [something similar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less#Possible_implementation) for `Node*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe what you actually want is to make `node_comparison` a *functor* (more specifically, a binary predicate):

```
struct node_comparison 
{
    bool operator () ( const Node* a, const Node* b ) const 
    {
        return a->totalWeight < b->totalWeight;
    }
};
```

A functor is a class whose objects provide an overload of the call operator (`operator ()`) and, therefore, can be invoked with the same syntax you would use for invoking a function:

```
Node* p1 = ...;
Node* p2 = ...;
node_comparison comp;
bool res = comp(p1, p2) // <== Invokes your overload of operator ()
```

Internally, `std::priority_queue` will instantiate your predicate more or less like I did in the code snippet above, and invoke it that way to perform comparisons between its elements.

---

The advantage of functors over regular functions is that they could hold *state* information (something you probably won't need for the moment, but which often turns out to be desirable):

```
#include <cmath>

struct my_comparator
{
    my_comparator(int x) : _x(x) { }

    bool operator () (int n, int m) const
    {
        return abs(n - _x) < abs(m - _x);
    }

    int _x;
};
```

The above predicate, for instance, compares integers based on how distant they are from another integer provided at construction time. This is how it could be used:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int pivot)
{
    my_comparator mc(pivot);
    std::priority_queue<int, std::deque<int>, my_comparator> pq(mc);

    pq.push(9);
    pq.push(2);
    pq.push(17);

    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        std::cout << pq.top();
        pq.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo(7);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    foo(10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need your comparison functor to implement `bool operator()(....)`, not `bool operator<(....)`:

```
struct node_comparison 
{
   bool operator()( const Node* a, const Node* b ) const 
   {
    return a->totalWeight < b->totalWeight;
   }
};
```