# Priority Queue of Nodes

Tags: c++, nodes, priority-queue

I've created a priority queue of Nodes, I've 'pushed' the node into the queue, with the assumption that it will sort the nodes in the order of the integer values. I guess I was wrong. The node has the properties, int freq, and char c. I want it sorted in order of ints, form the smallest to largest.

```
priority_queue<Node*> Q;
for(i =0; i< 95; i++){
    Q.push(node_array[i]);
}

for(i =0; i< 95; i++){
    cout<< Q.top() << endl;
    Q.pop();
}
```

How can I make it sort in order of the 'freq'?

Comment: Funny you should ask that, that was literally just asked moments ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646451/stl-priority-queue-and-overloading-with-pointers

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Probably some college assignment.

Comment: @sftrabbit I saw it and it doesn't seem to be related to my assignment. It would being funny if I knew the guy.

Comment: @AdegokeA The answers to the link I provided and the one you accepted below are for all intents and purposes identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your priority_queue comparison is comparing pointers, i.e. memory addresses. You need to provide a node comparison binary functor that takes two `Node*` and implements the desired logic:

```
struct node_cmp
{
   bool operator()( const Node* a, const Node* b ) const 
   {
    return a->someField < b->someField;
   }
};
```

The use it to instantiate the priority queue:

```
std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, node_cmp> Q;
```

Comment: How do I use this in the main() with the queue?

Comment: @AdegokeA I just added an example.

Comment: Why is std::vector<Node*> there? I tried priority_queue<Node*, node_cmp> Q; and got errors.

Comment: @AdegokeA `node_cmp` should be the **third** template parameter.  So the default *second* parameter must be specified.

Comment: @AdegokeA because `std::priority_queue` has three template parameters. The first one is the type and is mandatory. The following two are for the underlying container type, defaulted to `std::vector<T>`, and the comparison functor, defaulted to `std::less<T>`. If you want to specify the third, you need to specify the second too.

Comment: @AdegokeA *"I tried priority_queue<Node*, node_cmp> Q; and got errors "*  The solution in this answer works.  Why are you changing it in your comment above?  If you don't understand the syntax, I recommend posting a new question.

Comment: @DrewDormann I didn't make any changes. I clicked 'edit' by an accident.